# Search through Nested Hash having groups using Hashie Gem

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash of a PDF that is in this format:

```
[ { :page => 1, 
    :lines => [
      { :y => 774.0,
        :text_groups => [ { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } ]
      },
      # ...
    ]
  },
  { :page => 2, 
    :lines => [
      { :y => 774.0,
        :text_groups => [ { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } ]
      },
      # ...
    ],
    # ...
  }
]
```

I want to get the `:x` and `:y` for given `:text` from all 4 pages.

I tried this:

```
require 'hashie'

coordinates.extend(Hashie::Extensions::DeepLocate)
@hash_array = Hash.new
@hash_array = coordinates.deep_locate -> (key, value, object) { key == :text && value == "XXXX" }
```

This is giving me:

```
[ { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } }, 
  { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" }, 
  { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" }, 
  { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } ]
```

But I need `:x` and `:y` to be displayed like this:

```
x = " " and y = " "
```

I will use these values for my further validation.

Comment: It's not clear how your code relates to the example data you've provided. Your data has no values equal to `"YOUR DUE DATE CHANGE REQUEST"`.

Comment: I updated the question. I did not want to display any text that might be confidential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you'll accept a solution that doesn't use Hashie, but here's how I'd do it:

```
data = [
  { :page => 1, 
    :lines => [
      { :y => 774.0,
        :text_groups => [ { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } ]
      },
      # ...
    ]
  },
  { :page => 2, 
    :lines => [
      { :y => 774.0,
        :text_groups => [ { :x => 18.0, :width => 421.59599999999995, :text => "XXXX" } ]
      },
      # ...
    ],
    # ...
  }
]

SEARCH_TEXT = "XXXX"

coords = data.each_with_object([]) do |page, res|
  page[:lines].each do |line|
    line[:text_groups].each do |group|
      next unless group[:text] == SEARCH_TEXT
      res << { x: group[:x], y: line[:y] }
    end
  end
end

p coords
# => [ { :x => 18.0, :y => 774.0 },
#      { :x => 18.0, :y => 774.0 } ]
```

Comment: I have a question regarding the result that is being displayed. Is it a Hash array again ? or just a string ?

Comment: The result is an array of hashes. You can see where the hashes are created on this line: `res << { x: group[:x], y: line[:y] }`. If you want some other kind of result you can change it to your liking, e.g. `res << [ group[:x], line[:y] ]` or `res << "x = #{group[:x]} and y = #{line[:y]}"`. If you're going to do further processing of the data I recommend returning an array of hashes or an array of `[ x, y ]` arrays rather than an array of strings.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please feel free to accept it.

Comment: Your solution did help me resolve my problem. Thank you. I just did not know how to accept your answer. I accepted it now.